# Trying to add items added to cart to navbar

Tags: laravel

I an no expert in Laravel whatsoever, so I have no clue how to fix this problem. I have bought a template of laravel which I am trying to edit.

My website:
A website where you can buy/sell particular items.

My question:
If I am in the cart section of my website I can call my cartcount and do a foreach for each of my items so it shows up in my cart. I am trying to create a little shopping cart icon in my navbar that shows the items that are in my cart. The problem: It doesn't know my cart count because that apparently only works when I am in my Cart, and not on another page. Anyone that can help me out?
I am getting a not defined variable if I am not in the cart page.

I tried to add this in to my AppServiceProvider, but it tells me 'cart' is not known. (I am running laravel 5.3, that is why it is written like this)

```
view()->share('cart', $cart);
```

This is the controller that controls that part, I think (which is in ajax.php).

```
    // cart contents
public function cart_contents() {

    $cart = \Cart::content(true);

    return view('cart')->with( 'cart', $cart );
            view()->share('cart', $cart);
}
```

So it seems that my cart has already been shared, even though I can't seem to 'use' it on a different page than cart.page.blade.

I am using https://packagist.org/packages/kingpabel/shoppingcart for the shoppingcart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a variable in all your views just define it in your `AppServiceProvider` class (`apps/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`):

```
public function boot()
{
    View::share('cart', Cart::where(..)->get());
}
```

More information can be found in the [Laravel manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#sharing-data-with-all-views).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to add that line of code to the AppServiceProvider class but it spits out an error: Class 'App\Providers\View' not found.

Comment: I seem to have Cartcount working. Now the next problem arises: I am trying to do a foreach for each $cart as $item. But it does not understand what $cart is.

Comment: Have you defined $cart with View:share()? Please update your question with actual code. AppServiceProvider::boot() and your view should be fine.

Comment: I have added some code to my question. I hope it will help you out a bit.

Comment: $cart is not known in the AppServiceProvider because it is only defined in your Controller. Define it in in your AppServiceProvider: `$cart = \Cart::content(true); view()->share('cart', $cart);`.

Comment: I appreciate your help! I tried to add that code in to the AppServiceProvider and all the error's dissapeared. It doesn't show the correct output though. I also copied the code from my cart.blade into another blade to see if it worked in there, but it also didn't show the info (even though it does in cart.blade). Any idea how that happens?

Comment: I got it working! I changed @foreach($cart as $item) to @foreach( \Cart::content() as $item) and now it seems to be working. Thanks alot for your help, you helped it solve it :)